# PHP5: Cannot set time limit in safe mode issue

Tags: php, ini

Im trying to run a bigger php script FPDF with HTML2PDF script.
Im getting an "Cannot set time limit in safe mode" error and i have this in the top of my script. (I have it on 2 pages).

```
<?php
ini_get('safe_mode');
set_time_limit(0);
```

but im stil getting these 2 (3) errors.

> Warning: set_time_limit() [function.set-time-limit]: Cannot set time
>   limit in safe mode in /html2pdf.class.php on line 3
>
> Warning: set_time_limit() [function.set-time-limit]: Cannot set time
>   limit in safe mode in /_class/parsingCss.class.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   /_class/parsingCss.class.php on line 1242

Do someone have an ideer to fix this ?

I can't get to the php.ini file.

Comment: You can't set time limit in Safe Mode. Turn off safe mode OR make your PHP faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get an error, take that opportunity to read the docs. In this case, the docs for [set_time_limit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

> This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode. There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing the time limit in the php.ini.